# Can we post our own public domain text as documentation?

Tags: support, documentation, plagiarism

I've been working on a Mathematica project for a while that is released public domain (I would link it, but it's so far from usable at this point that it's not worth it). As part of this, I wrote some pretty comprehensive documentation of Mathematica's internal evaluation process. This was my own text and now released under public domain. It seems like it would be useful in the SO Documentation as well. It is acceptable for me to "plagiarize" my own public domain text in this context? Does this grant SO any rights to the text that would be in conflict?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is any conflict.

It doesn't limit you, the author: the CC-Wiki under which we publish here is non-exclusive. We don't give up any rights to our own content by publishing it here (except that it's permanently available here under the CC-Wiki license, and we can't take that back.)

It also doesn't matter to anyone looking to reuse your content. Technically, the content you publish through SO is subject to the CC-Wiki license and its restrictions - but because it is also available in the public domain, those restrictions don't matter. Public Domain trumps all. If anyone wanted to re-use your content in a way compatible with Public Domain but incompatible with CC-Wiki, they'll just use your Public Domain version.

I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure what the licensing here worked like. That clears it up a lot. I think I recall something about the CC-SA giving the right to revoke the content? Do you happen to know if that holds with CC-Wiki?

Comment: @Alex to my knowledge, it is irrevocable. The only right you have is to be disassociated from the content, e.g. having your name removed from it.